# Laravel Socket Subscribe

Tags: node.js, laravel, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have created a socket server in Node js. It is working fine while subscribing from an ejs file.

The part I'm confused is how do I keep my laravel application listening to the server I have created?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no plug-n-play method for this issue. You should create locally a service such as pusher: www.pusher.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel community already come up with a solution and it's call *Laravel Echo Server* (Check that out) that basically just a Node + socket.io that implement all the pub/sub logic for your Laravel app.

If you want to take complexity into your own hand then you could try setting up broadcasting driver in Laravel to use Redis. In simple term, Redis is the middleman that connect your Laravel app to your socket.io app for websocket connection. This is call message broker.

For example, you have Laravel app listening and publishing event on a Redis server and Node + Socket.io server doing the same thing. When you fire an event through Laravel, your node will able to listen to that event too through Redis acting as a broker. Your node then can instruct Socket.io to do whatever it want with its front-end user.

This solution doesn't require Laravel-echo but you need to do a lot of stuff for authentication, handling private channel and presence channel .. etc.

I suggest you take a look into Laravel Echo Server as what I've describe is only scratching the surface.